# How can I create a new page in my SharePoint site via Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need your help.

It is possible to create a web page on a sharepoint web site via Power Automate? I find some manuals with HTTP request, but some of theme are very old and other are not working bacause, e.g. I do not have the right URI.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following links, which may help you.

- [Create a SharePoint (Online) Subsite from Power Automate (Flow)](https://www.annajhaveri.com/sharepoint/create-a-sharepoint-online-subsite-from-power-automate-flow/)
- [Create SharePoint Site Pages automatically with Power Automate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtBqeEEOgdE)

Comment: Sorry I meant a page not a site